# How to separate screenshot from copy on clipboard in C#

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, clipboard, screenshot

I'm having a bit of a problem here. I want to save screenshots to my desktop using the application I build. To do that I need to recognize which images on the clipboard are from a screenshot and which images are copied. But I don't know how to do that and I have searched for an answer, but didn't find one.

The idea of the application is that it's always active on the background and that, whenever I press the PrintScreen button, it directly saves the image on my desktop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is impossible. Screenshots on the clipboard (put there by the PrtScn key) look like normal bitmaps.

Comment: Ok, but can I see how they got on the clipboard then? So see if someone put it on the clipboard by printscreen or copy.

Comment: Not in a safe way. You can receive notification of things being put on the clipboard (by being a [clipboard viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649016)). Applications can put data on the clipboard with an OLE link back to the original document, but this is optional, and the Windows PrtScn mechanism doesn't know about it.

Comment: Why?  If your goal is to make an app that saves screen captures to desktop when you press PrintScreen, make an app that trigger whenever PrintScreen is pressed.  What other ways are screen captures making their way to the clipboard?

Comment: I tried to do that, but nothing happened when I pressed PrintScreen. It worked with other buttons, so the code was, as far as I know, correct. Also it was an application that streamed everything that was put on the clipboard at first and from that application this idea came.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just make the application take a screenshot and save it for you?

This is probably the only way you are going to know for sure that the image you are saving is the screenshot that you want.

You can create a bmp screenshot like so:

```
Size s = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
```

And then save the bmp like this:

```
bmp.Save("PATHANDFILENAME");
```

**Update**

Based on that additional information, then you might be looking at a combination of saving the screenshot and using a global keyboard hook (**as provided by Tom**). Using the hook it should be possible to capture the printscreen being pressed and then capture and save the current screen. Also you might be able to cancel the printscreen being pressed and prevent it from copying the screen to the clipboard.

Comment: I already edited my question. The idea is that it workes directly when I press the PrintScreen button. So if there is a way to trigger the event in my application when I press the Print Screen button, this would be a good solution.

Comment: I checked with hotkeys which button was pressed and if it was the printscreen button my application did the printscreen and then saved the image. Thanks for the help people.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to distinguish real screenshot from fake, try embedding small change in picture that will be invisible to the eye but you will be able to detect from your code, for example pixel on location (2,2) on the client area of the form could have RGB values slightly altered (+3,+2,+1) - which will be unseen.

Look up [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm interesting. You could possibly combine this code to listen for Clipboard changes:

http://codeguru.earthweb.com/columns/dotnettips/article.php/c7315/

with some additional code to check the keystate prior.

Or, using a [global keyboard hook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx), you can listen for Ctrl+C or PrtScn then immediately check the clipboard. Of course, like the comments suggest, this isn't foolproof, but it's a start.

Comment: It doesn't need to be that foolproof just yet, because it's for personal use.